# How to call a method from within another method?

Tags: python, methods

I'm working on an n-gram language model. My specific question is fairly straight forward, as is my method `compute_bigram` is not successfully calling another method, `compute_unigram`. I want the former to call the latter.

If I instantiate an object of type, Model, comment out the line that calls compute_unigram, then call compute_unigram, followed by compute_bigram, no errors are raised.

However, if I only call compute_bigram, which should be calling compute_unigram, it raises a `None type error` (meaning the method was not called.)

```py
class DataLoader():
    def __init__(self,data,train_ratio):
        import operator

        self.all_sents = [sent for sent in data.sents()]
        num_ex = len(self.all_sents)
        num_train = int(train_ratio * num_ex)

        # processing vocab, adding special tokens to vocabulary
        self.full_vocab = [word.lower() for word in set(data.words())]
        self.vocab_count = {word:0 for word in self.full_vocab}
        for word in data.words():
            self.vocab_count[word.lower()] +=1

        self.sorted_count = sorted(self.vocab_count.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
        self.refined_vocab = [word for (word,count) in self.sorted_count if count > 50]
        self.refined_vocab.append('<ukn>')
        self.refined_vocab.append('<s>')
        self.refined_vocab.append('</s>')

        # process sentences, replace unknown characters with <UKN>, add <S> and </S> to start/stop of sentences as appropriate
        def process_sent(sent):
            sent = [word.lower() for word in sent]
            sent.insert(0,'<s>')
            sent.append('</s>')

            new_sent = [word if word in self.refined_vocab else '<ukn>' for word in sent]
            return new_sent

        self.sents = [process_sent(sent) for sent in self.all_sents]

        # create training and test sets as necessary
        self.train = [word.lower() for sent in self.sents[:num_train] for word in sent] 
        self.test =  [word.lower() for sent in self.sents[num_train:] for word in sent]  

        return None

class Model(DataLoader):

    def __init__(self,data,train_ratio,n,lambda_):

        self.n = n
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        super().__init__(data,train_ratio)
        self.root = {word:0 for word in self.refined_vocab}

    def compute_unigram(self):

        self.unigrams = {word:0 for word in self.refined_vocab}
        for i in self.train:
            self.unigrams[i] +=1

        word_count = 0
        for w1,count in self.unigrams.items():
            word_count += count

        for w1, count in self.unigrams.items():
            self.unigrams[w1] = count/word_count
        return None

    def compute_bigram(self):
        import copy

        self.unigrams = self.compute_unigram()

        self.bigrams = {word:copy.deepcopy(self.root) for word in self.refined_vocab}

        for idx, i in enumerate(self.train):
            try:
                pair = (i, self.train[idx+1])
                self.bigrams[pair[0]][pair[1]] +=1
            except:
                break

        for w1,w2_dict in self.bigrams.items():
            word_count = 0
            for w2, count in w2_dict.items():
                word_count += count

            for w2, count in w2_dict.items():
                total_mass = self.lambda_ * len(self.bigrams[w1].values())
                self.bigrams[w1][w2] = count/word_count + (total_mass * self.unigrams[w2])

        return None
```

Can anyone explain what I should be doing to enable one method to successfully call the other?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are making the call, and on what line the exception occurs?

Comment: `compute_unigram` returns `None`. Just call the function without assigning it to anything

Comment: If `compute_unigram` is setting `self.unigrams` directly, it doesn't need to return anything. As it is, you are undoing whatever work it does by assigning its return value of `None` to `self.unigrams`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.unigrams = self.compute_unigram()` cleans `self.unigrams`, as `compute_unigram()` ends with `return None`.
Remove the `self.unigrams =` part in that call.

> If I instantiate an object of type, Model, comment out the line that calls compute_unigram, then call compute_unigram, followed by compute_bigram, no errors are raised.

Yes, when you commented that line and called the method manually, the `self.unigrams = None` step did not happen.